# Why's type lattice in Scala?

Tags: scala, hierarchy, type-systems

I heard someone said:

> "Scala uses a type lattice rather than a type hierarchy, which is different from Java".

I do not quite understand what the meaning *type lattice* is and what the main difference between *type lattice* and *type hierarchy* is.

Could someone explain this term to me?

Comment: I don't think this is standard terminology. They may mean simply that traits permit a greater degree of multiple inheritance than java interfaces, or they may mean something else. Have you asked the person who said that what they mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its essentially means that : **The type hierarchy for Scala is a lattice, i.e. it has a “bottom” as well as a “top”.**

[image]

As seen from the image the top type here is `Any` and the bottom is `Nothing`.

Comment: Great Picture. Is it really a lattice though? I could define two traits `A` and `B` and two classes `C extends A with B` and `D extends A with B`, which would mean that there is no unique least upper bound.

Comment: Scala has a "join". It is called `with`. @KuluLimpa For your example, the greatest lower bound is the type `A with B with C with D`. I do not know if there is a "meet", so it may only be a join-semilattice rather a complete lattice.

Comment: @aij If I understand lattices well enough, Scala's LUB (join) of `C` and `D` is `AnyRef with A with B` (cause classes automatically extend `AnyRef`), and the GLB (meet) would just be `C with D`? Your example of `A with B with C with D` seems to not be the join (neither `C` nor `D` fulfill that type), but a verboser version of the meet instead (`A` and `B` are implied by `C` and `D`), right?